# Launching an RDS in a private subnet in VPC and access it from a web application

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have setup a VPC which has two subnets. One is a public subnet (I have Internet Gateway attached to it) and the other one is a private subnet. My web application resides inside the public subnet and it is a web facing subnet which can be accessed by the users. The database subnet resides inside the private subnet which cannot be accessed by the public. I have set the security group in such a way that the web application has only access to the database instance and not from the outside world.

Now the problem is I was installing a web application in the public subnet instance and I wanted to type in the database host and username and password.It didnt went through when I used the end point of rds `fdfdggtest.c1w3jii.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306`, it couldn't connect to the database, but when I used the host as `localhost` it connected with the database. Why does this happen.Is it that in VPC the RDS is considered as a local host?Please help me with why Im not able to connect with the endpoint which I got from the RDS.

Comment: I'd delete this question here and ask it over on ServerFault. It seems to be purely a system administration question and nothing specifically for a DBA.

Comment: @Colin'tHart There are similar questions asked and answered here in dba

Comment: @Ajis Can you point to examples? This really seems like a network/routing issue, nothing database-related, and perhaps may even be a question for Amazon support, not your peers.

Comment: Does the EC2 instance in the public subnet have permission (on RDS) to access the instance? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html for an example.